# href link wont apply

Tags: html, wordpress, wordpress-theming

look at here :

http://canz.co/studio/

in the graphic section under Graphic Design when you click " View more Information: nothing happens

my code in that section is like this :

```
[columns]
[two_third]
[animated_item]
<img class="size-full wp-image-536" alt="Ipad" src="http://canz.co/studio/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/Ipad.png" width="80%" height="auto" />
[/animated_item]
[/two_third]

[one_third]
[animated_item]
[block_title title1='GAME APPLICATION' title2='

Canz studio provides a completely unique design service incorporating every element of graphic design and supply.

We pride ourselves on our client care and quailty of design and we work with clients from all around the world.

']
[/animated_item]
[animated_item]

<a href="http://canz.co/studio-int/" title="http://canz.co/studio-int/"><button class="general_button type_1"><b>VIEW MORE INFORMATION</b></button>
</a>
[/animated_item]
[/one_third]
[/columns]
```

anyone knows what is the issue here?

Answer (score 0):

it seems `do_shortcode` function omit the hyperlink link  or may be extract the shortcodes function prevent to output

So why don't you try with `onclick` attribute

Change

```
<a href="http://canz.co/studio-int/" title="http://canz.co/studio-int/"><button class="general_button type_1"><b>VIEW MORE INFORMATION</b></button>
```

to

```
<button onclick="http://canz.co/studio-int/" class="general_button type_1"><b>VIEW MORE INFORMATION</b></button>
```

Comment: replaced the code but still wont do anything , the code is now online on the site

Comment: id ? you mean create an id in my style css and link it here?

Comment: no just `id="test"` to check wheather it output or not